# Finding unique numbers in every iteration python

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is the problem: https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/6254486/dashboard

The output should be:

Input

```
5
0
1
2
11
1692
```

Output

```
Case #1: INSOMNIA
Case #2: 10
Case #3: 90
Case #4: 110
Case #5: 5076
```

My output:

```
Case #1: INSOMNIA
Case #2: 39916800
Case #3: 79833600
Case #4: 3991680
Case #5: 8527680
```

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

```
T = int(raw_input())

final = []
for i in range(T):
    c = 2    
    n = int(raw_input())

    a = []    
    while True:    
        if n == 0:
            final.append(0)
            break

        b = set(str(n))    
        for d in b:
            if int(d) not in a:
                a.append(int(d))

        if len(a) == 10:
            final.append(n)
            break

        n = n*c
        c += 1   

for i in range(T):
    if final[i] == 0:
        print "Case #%d: INSOMNIA" %(i+1)
    else:
        print "Case #%d: %d" %(i+1,final[i])
```

Comment: the 0 case looks like it would be easiest to debug. You should start with zero and walk through the program with paper and pencil, or mentally, or with a debugging tool, and see what happens. I mean, you're doing a code jam problem so you probably want to become a better programmer. There's a quote somewhere about how programming is 95% debugging and only 5% coding.

Comment: input is 6 cases, output is 5.. What's up with that?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis The first line in input is number of test cases. The following are the test cases.

Comment: why do you have `raw_input()` twice?

Comment: `n = n * c` - this is not what you want.

Comment: @JulianCienfuegos  Thank you for your input. I realized my mistake but what i realized even more is to keep trying harder before asking for help. It was probably a stupid mistake on my end but I'll make sure I don't repeat it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not generating the series correctly. The key is on line 39 (`n = n*c`).

Your series should be `n, 2n, 3n, 4n, ...`
Your method generates `n, c*n = 2*n = 2n, c*n = 3*2n = 6n, c*n = 4*6n = 24n, ...`

In short, you're reassigning the value of `n` on each iteration. You need to store the most recently generated term in a variable *other* than `n`. You'll have three variables. `n` is fixed, `c` increments by 1 each term, `term` is calculated by `c*n`.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that and posted the updated code before seeing your comment. I should have tried harder to solve the problem. Thanks for your help anyways!

Answer (score 0):

After debugging:
I'm sorry for not trying harder.

Here's the solution:

```
T = int(raw_input())

final = []

for i in range(T):

    c = 2

    n = int(raw_input())



    a = []

    w = n

    while True:

        if w == 0:
            final.append(0)
            break

        b = set(str(w))

        for d in b:
            if int(d) not in a:
                a.append(int(d))

        if len(a) == 10:
            final.append(w)
            break

        w = n*c
        c += 1

for i in range(T):
        if final[i] == 0:
            print "Case #%d: INSOMNIA" %(i+1)
        else:
            print "Case #%d: %d" %(i+1,final[i])
```

The problem was that I was changing the initial value of n in every loop. So instead of multiplying it by an increasing counter I multiplied it with itself and the counter.

Instead using w = n*c was the correct approach.

As i can see from the down votes and comments, everyone is pissed of on me for not debugging more than I had. I understand that and will keep that in mind.
The way i got to the solution was using a few print statements to know where exactly the problem was occurring.

Comment: print statements are definitely your friend in this kind of situation =)